# HTML5 code reuse Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

Hello Fellow developers,

I am embarking on a new journey to develop HTML5/JS web site and looking a ways to reuse the same code for Mobile App (Would like to use it using PhoneGap or Appcelerator). The requirement is to develop once which can be used on desktop, and smartphones, but project sponser wants more secure way to handle data on smartdevices and hence we would like to choose this approach. Now my questions is

1. Can we reuse and architect the solution this way to reuse HTML5/jQuery code on Mobile  within Appcelerator or Phonegap?
2. If yes, what percentage of rework will be required to support on mobile devices?
3. If no, what could be alternatives?

thanks all for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1).
If your current desktop website interact with server-side in webservice way,everything will be done very easy. Even you can directly modify the *.java in src\com\ like this:

```
 super.loadUrl("http://balabalabala.com");
```

With phonegap wrap, your app can be access right now.
If not, you will need spend time in implementing the server-side interfaces for client-side.

(2).
You need to refactor your static html page with some javascript framework for mobile(such as jquery mobile,sencha touch).
Using them to make your phonegap app more simalar with native app.
That takes time too.

The 2 things above are what you need rework.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are planning to build a mobile website. If so, its very easy to convert it to a PhoneGap app with may be only 5% changes provided your website uses only HTML5,JS and CSS. Its not possible to run a a website written in serverside languages such as PHP, ASP.NET, ruby etc.  Some important items to keep in mind:

- start development of website and app together. test with mobile browser and phonegap so that you can fix issues as and when they arise.
- use a mobile HTML5 based framework like Kendo UI Mobile/ jQuery Mobile etc for developement
  so that you dont spend time fixing all the mobile related UI stuff.
- Wherever you are using PhoneGap features, check whether you are running on PhoneGap or else fall back to the browser feature.